# Image format for mask

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, mask

What format can be used to make masks that takes least space? what I need is only 8 bit alpha channel (no color and nothing else). I need it for an iPhone application so everything that can easily be opened with `UIImage` will be good (list of them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW3)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `png`. When compiling Xcode optimizes `png`s for performance on iOS and for using with `UIImage` whereas it does not do the same for other formats, rendering any external optimizations futile except for extreme circumstances.

Comment: by what I seen in my mac, it seems apple prefers `TIFF` over `PNG`, will it get the same optimizations? also a link to an article about those optimizations will help.

Comment: It will not. PNG is handled specially on iOS devices. See this article for a good explanation: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html

Comment: Here's this little png-8 to png-24 comparison I once made. Though I now added ones without the highlight to show how png-8 handles basic shadows ( which is pretty good.. ) http://photoshopmesta.net/1/MaskIT/index.html -Im gonna add one with no shadow or highlight as well.. just got thinking that it might be good as well.